# Custom SearchView crash on Release build

Tags: android, searchview, android-proguard

I'm getting a crash when trying to get a reference to a Custom SearchView class in onCreateOptionsMenu. Normally this works fine but when loading the release apk, it crashes. I tried adding these lines to my proguard but its still crashing:

```
# Android support
-keep public class com.mine.mobile.mypackage.usercontrol.SearchViewCustom
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
```

Here is the code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        mMenu = menu;
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_invest, menu);
        final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_invest_search);

        if (searchItem != null) {
            mSearchView = (SearchViewCustom) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

            SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
            mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        }

        mPresenter =  new BaseActivityPresenterImpl(this,mSearchView,mMenu,searchItem);
        mPresenter.setupActionBar(NONE,false);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Here is the log

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.mine.mobile.mypackage.usercontrol.d.setSearchableInfo(android.app.SearchableInfo)' on a null object reference
!   1   at com.mine.mobile.mypackage.activity.home.a.onCreateOptionsMenu(BaseActivity.java:94)
2   at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:3232)
3   at android.support.v4.app.q.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:362)
4   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:98)
5   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:335)
6   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:98)
7   at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:454)
8   at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:61)
9   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
10  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
11  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:616)
12  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
13  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
14  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
15  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
16  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247)
17  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
18  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
19  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_delete"
        android:title="@string/delete"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_white"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_done"
        android:title="@string/done"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_done_white"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_refresh_white"
        android:visible="false"
        android:title="@string/refresh_menu"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_invest_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white"
        android:visible="false"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:actionViewClass="com.mine.mobile.mypackage.usercontrol.SearchViewCustom"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />
</menu>
```

This is not a duplicate of What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it? ...that question encompasses way too broad a category

Comment: can you share your menu.xml

Comment: Added menu.xml to question

Comment: Try using the apk profiler in Android Studio 3 to see if your custom class is where you expect it to be and hasn't been obfuscated to a different name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Kuffs I don't have Android studio 3 I have 2.3.3

Comment: Nothing stops you installing 3 alongside it

Comment: @Zoe no not a duplicate of that

Comment: @Zoe absolutely not a duplicate of What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?... as that question encompasses way too broad a category

Comment: @Mike6679 your error seems to be related to your proguard config are you sure you have the class in the same package

Comment: @ColdFire my custom SearchView is definitely in com.mine.mobile.mypackage.usercontrol

Comment: anyone? no suggestions? I'm trying variations in proguard to no avail

Comment: Are you sure it's not too early to call the service there? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14451407/nullpointerexception-when-calling-getsystemservicecontext-location-service-and

Comment: nope, works fine in non release build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was on the right track but apparently my pro guard syntax was incorrect (I used google's example [here:](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html)).  This worked though:

```
-keep public class com.mine.mobile.mypackage.usercontrol.SearchViewCustom {
  public *;
}
```